# Why my program couldn't import classes from jars

Tags: java, spring, jar

My program was executing fine and there were no errors for import classes from jar while ago but i am having  errors now to import classes from lib and warning symbol appearing on  WEB-INF folder. I don't know the reason why it occurring if anyone has solution let me know with reason.

[image]

Comment: Did you use the dependency manager to include your dependencies?

Comment: no I didn't use dependency manager

Comment: Try to add the jar-files with rightclicking on your project. Build Path -> Configure Buildpath. Then go on tab Libraries. Then Click the Button "Add External JARs". Then add your jars in your WEB/Lib Folder. But i recommend that you use gradle or maven for depenencymanagement. :)

Comment: k tnx my errors and warnings disappeared after added all jars inside java buildpath libraries like you mentioned

Comment: Okey :). Can you please give me a flag? :)

Comment: sorry @noixes i don't have option for give you flag  because i have only 6 reputation. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Mma0iNtwnGNDN2MUdOcjlOZHM/view?usp=drivesdk